# Show Wallpaper with AppCompat Theme (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, android-theme

Okay, I cannot seem to find a solution. For a launcher app, I want to use a theme that sets the wallpaper as the background. So far, I tried using

```
 @android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar
```

But I need AppCompat functionality in my app, and that requires an AppCompat theme. Maybe there is something I looked over...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```